# How to prompt user to enroll biometrics on their phone

Tags: flutter, biometrics

I am using [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) for biometric authorization.

In case that the device does have biometric support but the user has not enrolled any biometrics (i.e. `auth.getAvailableBiometrics()` is empty) is there a way to launch the phone's screen that prompts the user to enrol their biometric data?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I've never done this type of authorization myself, so I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `local_auth` package for implementing this

To check whether there is local authentication available on this device or not, call `canCheckBiometrics` (if you need biometrics support) and/or `isDeviceSupported()` (if you just need some device-level authentication):

```
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
final bool canAuthenticateWithBiometrics = await 

auth.canCheckBiometrics;
final bool canAuthenticate = canAuthenticateWithBiometrics || await auth.isDeviceSupported();
```

Reference doc: [Flutter - local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth)

**UPDATE**

You can launch the `security settings` (where fingerprint option is available) using the below code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
```

with `API >= P` there is `Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL` & `BiometricPrompt`.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private void startFingerprintEnrollment(@NonNull AppCompatActivity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMENT);
}
```

For `API >= M`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void gotoSecuritySettings(@NonNull AppCompatActivity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't launch the screen to enrol the biometrics on the phone if the user hasn't done so previously